# Rebus #13 for brain gymnastics

Tags: rebus

Giving speeches isn't as fun as making rebuses.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Orator. Because oar + 8 + oar.

Comment: I'm speechless how fast you got that!  Kudos! Written out, the number contains your "missing text."

Comment: Oh sorry, I was on my mobile and I just wanted to post the answer asap :P